# Best possibe bound for the number of solutions of diophantine approximation?

Tags: nt.number-theory, diophantine-approximation

I am interested in an explicit - best possible - bound for the number of solutions of the simple diophantine equation
$$\tag{1}|\mu_1 n - \mu_2 m| <1,$$
where $m,n \in \mathbb{Z}$ with $|n| \leq |\mu_1|^{-1} N^2$ and $|m| \leq |\mu_2|^{-1} N^2$. Here $\mu_1$ and $\mu_2$ are real numbers, say $|\mu_2| \geq |\mu_1| \geq 1$.

> Additionally, we should also suppose that $\mu_1/\mu_2$ is irrational.

Moreover, I always have $|n| \gg |\mu_1|^{-1/2} N$ and $|m| \gg |\mu_2|^{-1/2} N$. and $N \geq \max \{|\mu_1|,|\mu|\}$.

One usual (and quite simple) argument is to observe that this number is bounded by the number of solutions of
$$|\tfrac{\mu_1}{\mu_2} n-m| < 1$$
and this is bounded by the corresponding volume. Thus, one possible bound is $|\mu_1|^{-1}N^2$. Alternatively, one can show also the better bound $|\mu_2|^{-1} N^2$.

> Question: Is it possible to improve the bound for (1) up to $|\mu_1 \mu_2|^{-1} N^2$? Here we may allow that the implicit constant depends on the ratio $\mu_1/\mu_2$.

If not: Can we restrict $\mu_1$ and $\mu_2$ to some class of numbers for which the statement is true? For example, if $\mu_1/\mu_2$ is an algebraic number?

Alternatively, now $\mu_1$ and $\mu_2$ may seen as fixed (and thus the explicit dependency can be repressed), I can restate (1) by
$$\tag{2} |\mu_1 n - \mu_2 m | < \varepsilon$$
and the question may reformulated by asking if the number of solutions of (2) can be bounded by $\epsilon^{1-\eta}$, where $\epsilon^{-\eta/2} \ll |n|,|m| \ll \epsilon^{-\eta}$ and here $\eta >1$.

Comment: The bound $|\mu_1|^{-1}N^2$ that you claim is not correct. For $|\mu_1|>N^2$, it would imply that there are no solutions of (1), while $m=n=0$ is always a solution. Note also that for $\mu_1=\mu_2=\mu$, any pair with $m=n$ solves (1), hence the number of solutions is $\gg 1+|\mu|^{-1}N^2$.

Comment: As I said, let suppose that $\mu_1/\mu_2$ is irrational. Then we must have $\mu_1 \neq \mu_2$. Additionally, $|n| \gg |\mu_1| ^{-1/2} N$ and $m \gg |\mu_2| ^{-1/2} N$ implies that $m=n=0$ is not a permissible solution.

Comment: I have added an alternative formulation of my question. I am not sure, but in view of the inefficiency of Roth's theorem (and related results) the question is maybe beyond the current state of research ...

Comment: If $\mu_1$ and $\mu_2$ are very close to each other (in terms of $N$), we still have $\gg |\mu_1|^{-1}N^2$ trivial solutions $m=n$ in the range you indicate. Hence the bound you indicate cannot be improved in general. This has nothing to do with the ineffectivity in Roth's theorem.

Comment: In the meantime, I have also come to conclustion that the bounds in my first question cannot be improved. Thus, I have added an alternative formulation, where $\mu_1$ and $\mu_2$ are fixed and $\varepsilon$ is variable in the sense that we are interested in the behaviour for $\varepsilon \downarrow 0$. (This question is of couse highly related to Roth's theorem, because here I ask how many 'good' approximants we can find ...)

Comment: For large $N$ the number of solution will be more or less equal to the volume, and that cannot be improved.

Answer (score 1):

The references [1] and [2] could be the answer to your question.

[1] Laurent, Michel; Nogueira, Arnaldo. Inhomogeneous  approximation  with  co-
prime integers and lattice orbits. arXiv:1110.5467.

[2] Alan Haynes. Inhomogeneous approximation by coprime integers, New York Journal of Mathematics New York J. Math. 18 (2012) 249–259.

Comment: Both references are interesting! However, in this papers the main focus is on **inhomogeneous diophantine equations**. And all theorms show only the existence of infinity many coprime $(p,q)$ without explicit upper bounds. As Kurisuto Asutora has commented, I also think that it cannot be improved.